# Cosmos DB - Why partition key has to be mentioned when making point queries using sql api SDK?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

Why partition key has to be mentioned when making point queries against partitioned collection using sql api SDK?

Is there way to execute point queries against partitioned collection using sql api SDK without mentioning "PartitionKey"?  as it is point query.

Working Example:
 // - db_id is the ID property of the Database
 // - coll_id is the ID property of the DocumentCollection
 // - doc_id is the ID property of the Document wish to read.
  var docUri = UriFactory.CreateDocumentUri("db_id", "coll_id", "doc_id");
await docClient.ReadDocumentAsync(docUri, new RequestOptions { PartitionKey = new PartitionKey(actualId) });

Non working example:
  var docUri = UriFactory.CreateDocumentUri("db_id", "coll_id", "doc_id");
  await docClient.ReadDocumentAsync(docUri);

Below query without partition key, fails with errormessage: "PartitionKey value must be supplied for this operation."

Why partition key needs to be mentioned for point query against partitioned collection?

Answer (score 0):

PartitionKey is mandatory, When you create an account you will be asked to provide the Partition Key. It is used for sharding and it acts as a logical partition for your data, provides Cosmos DB with a natural boundary for distributing data [`across partitions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/partition-data). So it comes with the design.

So whenever you are querying data from cosmosdb with SDK it is necessary to pass the PartitionKey

The reason ParitionKey is needed because that CosmosDB does not parse the query until it locates the data.

Comment: that is why you need to pass the partitionKey

Comment: Thanks, I understand the role of partition key. But my query is about the need of partition query when I making db request using point queries. For example "SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.id = "foo" if "id" is partition key which already part of query, still I explicitly has to mention id is partition while I sql api SDK?

Comment: yes you need to explicitly mention because cosmosdb works in a way that it first identify where the data is located first and then execute the query.

Comment: But going by msdn url "https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.documents.client.documentclient.readdocumentasync?view=azure-dotnet" no need to mention partition key. When I use the same code in my application against partitioned collection it fails but with non-partitioned collection it works, how? & why?.Please